# ubuntu 14.04 bash script permission error reading file into variable with $()

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu-14.04

I have a bash script placed in a directory under my logged-in users home directory which read a file (also placed in same users home directory, deeper in the path relative to the bash script) to hold some variable for further processing in the script (simplified here for genericness):

```
#!/bin/bash
sEnv=$(./config/myfile.conf)
echo $sEnv
```

when running this file from bash with

```
. run-me.sh
```

the script fails with this error:

```
-bash: ./config/myfile.conf: Permission denied
```

permissions on the file is:
    -rw-rw-r--

I'm unsure what the issue is (I'm a failry noob Linux / ubuntu user)..

Hope to get some help on this.

Regards,

Henrik

Comment: Hi OhmegaStar, welcome to SO. Please don't forget to comeback and upvote+accept the answer that you find most helpful to you. This benefits you, those trying to solve your problem, and the wider community at large. It's also the way in which we say 'thank you' around here. Best regards.

Comment: Hi Ray, Answer accepted and upmarked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read a file into a variable, you need `$(<file)`:

```
#!/bin/bash
sEnv=$(<./config/myfile.conf)
echo $sEnv
```

However, if the config file is setting (environment) variables in shell style, you might prefer to source the file (thus copying the contents to your script):

```
. ./config/myfile.conf
#or alternatively
source ./config/myfile.conf
```

Comment: Hi Manuel,
Thanks for the answer, this helped me resolving the issue, i also found that `sEnv=$(cat ./config/myfile.conf)` worked, although it seems excessive.

Answer (score 0):

`$(command)` executes `command`, so `command` has to be executable. Try

```
$ chmod 775 config/myfile.conf
$ . run-me.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

The `$(command)` actually tries to execute whatever's inside (i.e. `command`).

Here, the file *must* itself be:

- executable: it must have the `x` permission (e.g. `chmod 755 filename`)
- a program: the contents should be code, in either source or object/binary form

Comment: Beat you by 14 seconds. ;-)

Comment: @blm: True -.-, but mine has a more thorough explanation ^-^ :P

Comment: Well, technically, your explanation isn't correct, the file doesn't have to be a script, it can be a compiled executable. Also, in the general case, `command` can be a function, alias, and probably some other things. That's easy to fix though so let's call it a tie. :-)

Comment: @blm: In context, the idea was that it had to be a program. But yes, you're correct that it does not need to be a *script* specifically. It could be any program in source (e.g. a script) or object/binary form (built-in command, etc). I've made the minor updates :)

Answer (score 0):

Make the `./config/myfile.conf` executable:

```
chmod u+x ./config/myfile.conf
```

Also its a good idea to check whats inside `./config/myfile.conf` first, read permission on a regular `conf` file would normally suffice. Check what meets your requirement and set permissions accordingly, don't do anything unnecessary.